# Recursive Operation in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
vals = {"operator": [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5], "nextval": [2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(vals)

   operator  nextval
0         1        2
1         1        3
2         1        6
3         2        4
4         3        5
5         5        6
```

What I'm trying to do is get a list of all the possible paths from a starting point, like 1, and an ending point, like 6, using the operators and nextvals, not strictly the shortest path.
The output can be flexible, but I'm looking for something like this or that communicates this:

```
1 -> 6
1 -> 2 -> 4 
1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 6
```

I'm able to get it close, but not sure how to get the recursion right since the dict can't handle 2 same keys:

```
import pandas as pd

vals = {"operator": [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5], "nextval": [2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(vals)

df1 = df.set_index("operator")

dictvals = {}
for x in df1.index.unique():
    dictvals[x] = []
    df2 = df1.loc[x]
    if isinstance(df2, pd.DataFrame):
        for idx, rowdata in df2.iterrows():
            dictvals[x].append(rowdata["nextval"])
    else:
        dictvals[x] = df2[0]

print(dictvals) 

{1: [2, 3, 6], 2: 4, 3: 5, 5: 6}
```

Comment: What should happen if, for example, there are two rows like `1 2` and `2 1`? But for what it's worth, the general problem you describe is building a *directed graph* and then finding all *traversals* from a given root node to a dead end; that should help your web searching.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Let's assume there will not be anything circular.

Comment: So, a directed *acyclic* graph, then, which may help you further.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks for the info. I have done graphs in databases, but not Python yet. I'll take a look. Any preference on libraries or packages for working with python graphs?

Comment: `networkx` is a common graph library.

Comment: networkx with path ~ start root and leaf ~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check with `networkx` , you need a direction graph with `'root'` to `'leaf'` path

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,source='operator',target='nextval', edge_attr=None, create_using=nx.DiGraph())
road=[]
for n in G:
       if G.out_degree(n)==0: #leaf
           road.append(nx.shortest_path(G, 1, n))
           
road
Out[82]: [[1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 5, 6]]
```

Update

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,source='operator',target='nextval', edge_attr=None, create_using=nx.DiGraph())
road=[]
for n in G:
       if G.out_degree(n)==0: #leaf
           road.append(list(nx.all_simple_paths(G, 1, n)))
           
road
Out[509]: [[[1, 3, 5, 6], [1, 6]], [[1, 2, 4]]]
```

Comment: This is a great solution start, thanks. However, one thing I'm concerned about is this is pulling the shortest path. I probably wasn't clear in the post, but I'm looking for all directed paths and permutations, not just the shortest. I have updated the post to include an additional data point to highlight this.

Comment: @dfundako check the update switch to `all_simple_paths` :-)

Answer (score 4):

Let's try to hand-roll a solution, because thinking about this kind of recursive algorithm is educational. (Of course it is appropriate to just use an existing library in the real world; it will probably be much more fault-tolerant.)

The code you show builds a recognizable representation of the graph itself, but it would be better to use lists (or sets, or tuple) for the values even when there is only one successor node, for consistency. I would argue that sets make the most sense here, since if there are duplicate entries in the input then we should discard the duplicate graph nodes. So let us suppose we start with:

```
graph = {1: {2, 3}, 2: {4}, 3: {5}, 5: {6}}
```

We have agreed to restrict ourselves to considering directed acyclic graphs. I propose that the paths from our root node can be found recursively as follows: recursively check *each* path from *each* successor node; accumulate these results, and prepend each with the link from the root to the corresponding successor.

Of course, when we write recursive code we like to avoid side effects, since they make it harder to reason. So let us instead say: the accumulation of all paths, defined as (link from node to successor) + (path from successor to end), for each successor, for each pat from that successor. Of course, the way we represent the "link from node to successor" is just the current node name and an arrow; we get the rest of the path from the recursion, including the successor name.

And then we need a base case: if there are no successors, then we have a single path from here to the end (since we are at an end), which is just that node name by itself. It would be simpler for our code if the dead ends in our graph were represented with empty sets; but it's clearly easier to *generate* the graph just omitting those keys. So we'll lean on `dict.get` rather than indexing when we make the check.

Well, that first part sounds an awful lot like a list comprehension to me (with two `for` clauses`. For the base case, to match that, we need a list containing one path. That gives us:

```
def paths(graph, root):
    successors = graph.get(root, set())
    if not successors:
        return [str(root)] # a single path starting here and going nowhere.
    return [
        f'{root} -> {path}'
        for successor in successors
        for path in paths(graph, successor)
    ]
```

Let's try it:

```
>>> paths({1: {2, 3}, 2: {4}, 3: {5}, 5: {6}}, 1)
['1 -> 2 -> 4', '1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 6']
```

Alternatively, you could use generator expressions instead of list comprehensions, or even write it as a recursive generator (using `yield` and `yield from`).

(If we are feeling cheeky enough, we can continue the functional-programming theme by using a conditional expression:)

```
def paths(graph, root):
    successors = graph.get(root, set())
    return [
        f'{root} -> {path}'
        for successor in successors
        for path in paths(graph, successor)
    ] if successors else [str(root)]
```